# Set terminating character in Flyway for DB2 procedure creation

Tags: flyway

I am trying to create a db2 stored procedure, and grant privileges to it in a Flyway migration. I am running 2.1.1.

The procedure includes semi-colons with it. I can create the procedure fine directly on db2 (starting my connection with db2 +td@) by setting the @ character as the terminating character.

How do we go about setting the terminating character for our Flyway migrations?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need it. Flyway deals with begin ... end; blocks just fine, even if they contain semicolons.

If you have a case that doesn't work, please file an issue in the issue tracker with a small sample migration that causes trouble.